# How can I render the devise signin and signup views on the layout to be available on all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

I want to show the devise login and signup pages on all views of my application, so it can be publicly accessible from anywhere, How can achieve this so I dont need to use the devise requests to show only the login or signup form?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the views from devise (mainly good for more customization) by running

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This will extract the devise views into your app/views path. Take the forms from there and add them to your existing application template.

See the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) for more information.